# How to align headers in Bokeh TableColumn

Tags: python, bokeh

I am using Bokeh TableColumn to produce a data table in an interactive dashboard.  I would like to right align the three numeric columns.  However, the headings remain left aligned and do not line up with the numbers in the column.

Is there a way to right align the headers in a Bokeh TableColumn?

I have search stackoverflow and do not believe this has a solution.  A minimum working example of what I am trying to do (with synthetic data) is below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file, curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import layout, row, column, Spacer, widgetbox
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, DataTable, TableColumn, DateRangeSlider, Slider, BoxAnnotation, HoverTool
from bokeh.models.widgets import NumberFormatter, DateFormatter, RangeSlider, Toggle, Button, CheckboxButtonGroup, Div

np.random.seed(10)
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'date':pd.date_range(start='1/1/2000', periods=200, freq='Q'),
    'x': np.random.choice(range(100),200)
})

data['qrtly'] = round(data['x'].pct_change(),4)
data['tty'] = round(data['x'].pct_change(periods=4),4)
source = ColumnDataSource(data)

columns = [
    TableColumn(field='date', title='', formatter=DateFormatter(format='%b-%Y')),
    TableColumn(field='x', title='levels', formatter=NumberFormatter(text_align='right')),
    TableColumn(field='qrtly', title='qrtly', formatter=NumberFormatter(format='0.00%',text_align='right')),
    TableColumn(field='tty', title='tty', formatter=NumberFormatter(format='0.00%',text_align='right'))
]

table = DataTable(source=source, columns=columns, width=635)

curdoc().add_root(table)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method that use css to do it:

give the table a css class:

```
table = DataTable(source=source, columns=columns, width=635, css_classes=["my-table"])
```

then use following style to right align the levels columns:

```
.my-table .slick-header-column:nth-child(3) .slick-column-name{
    float:right !important;
}
```

You can add style by using Div

```
from bokeh.models.widgets import Div
table = DataTable(source=source, columns=columns, width=635, css_classes=["my-table"])
style = Div(text="""
<style>
.my-table .slick-header-column:nth-child(3) .slick-column-name{
    float:right !important;
}
</style>
""")
show(column(table, style))
```

Comment: Hello HYRY.  I have tried to get your solution working buy saving the second snippet into a file titled my-table.css in the same folder as the python script. But nothing happened  (ie the headers are still left aligned). Could you please expand your answer a little to help me resolve this?  I will then accept the answer and uprate it.